# How to activate (open keyboard) EditText after a delay time?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have an EditText and a CountDownTimer. Normally if u start an Activity with an EditText the EditText gets activatet and the Keyboard shows up. But I want that the Activity starts, the timer goes down and THEN the Keyboard shows up automatically.
How can i do this?

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          //Do Something
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             //Keyboard pop up
         }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Let me wrong if i am wrong, you want that when activity start you dont want to focus edit text and after your timer goes down then you want to show keyboard. So what you can do is when activity load make you edit text focusable false, and after timer task make it focusable true and request focus to your edittext.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using a `Handler` with the `postDelayed(...)` method and open the keyboard after your specified delay time:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Handler h = new Handler();

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }

    }, 5000); // delay in milliseconds
}
```

This will **open the Keyboard after your desired delay time.**

Here my **.xml file**: (please note the `<requestFocos />` tag)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Both doesn't work for me. Nothing shows up. Or has it to be final EditText?

Comment: It needs to be final or a member variable, otherwise it won't be visible inside the run() method.

Comment: Still nothing shows up. Do I first (at onCreate) have to remove focus or disable the EditText?

Comment: And i have the Runnable in the onCreate method too is that okay?

Comment: Yes that is ok, give me a second i will try it myself

Comment: Allright I updated my answer with the full code I am using. It works I just tested it.

Comment: Ah okay that was missing ;) Thank you!